# Regex to check if a path go only down

Tags: php, regex, security, path, filepath

I want to test if a path given by the user go down like:

`my/down/path`

at the opposite of:

`this/path/../../go/up`

for security reasons.

I already made this:

```
return (bool)preg_match('#^([a-z0-9_-])+(\/[a-z0-9_-])*$#i', $fieldValue);
```

But the user should be allowed to use the `'.'` in his path (like: `my/./path`, that not useful but he can) and I don't know how to consider it.

I'm then looking for a secure regex to check this.

Thanks

edit: After viewing answers, yes it would be fine if the test check if the real path (removing `'.'` and `'..'`) is a down path.

Comment: I added the [security] tag which should get the question more attention and, hopefully, perhaps from someone who knows of a good PHP path traversal library. As my response suggests, this is a non-trivial problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not want to check that a path doesn't contain `..` but instead want to check that if evaluated as whole, it doesn't go up. E.g. `./path/..` is still in `.`, even though it contains `..`.

You can find an implementation of [path depth validation in Twig](https://github.com/nikic/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php#L138):

```
$parts = preg_split('#[\\\\/]+#', $name);
$level = 0;
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    if ('..' === $part) {
        --$level;
    } elseif ('.' !== $part) {
        ++$level;
    }

    if ($level < 0) {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

Twig does not use `realpath` for the validation, because `realpath` has issues with paths in Phar archives. Additionally `realpath` only works if the pathname already exists.

Comment: I've added a response that distinguishes path depth validation from path traversal validation. Nothing personal against your response, but since OP mentioned security I wanted to have at least one answer which addressed more hostile environments.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply check if the realpath of the user supplied path begins with the allowed path:

```
function isBelowAllowedPath($allowedPath, $pathToCheck)
{
    return strpos(
        realpath($allowedPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $pathToCheck), 
        realpath($allowedPath)
    ) === 0;
}
```

[Demo on codepad](http://codepad.org/J4OtU6LO)

Note that this will also return `false` for directories that do not exist below `$allowedPath`.

Comment: Depending on what exactly you need this for `realpath` might not be applicable. `realpath` requires the pathname to exist, i.e. you can't use this check for creation of new paths. Additionally `realpath` will fail for some edge cases like Phar archives.

Answer (score 1):

The previous responses (including the accepted one) address path depth but not path traversal.  Since the question specifically mentioned that this is for security, then casual checking such as that described so far may not be sufficient.

For example,

- Do you care about traversing through hard or soft links below the current working directory?
- Does the system you are on (or could potentially deploy to) support unicode?
- How many things are evaluating the string in question before or after your PHP code sees it?  The web server?  The shell?  Something else?

Suppose I send your script a string like `./..%2f../`?  Is it important to your application that this string will take me up two levels?  Or that the scripts provided in other answers will not catch this because it doesn't evaluate to `..`?

What about `./\.\./`?  If the path is parsed by splitting on both `\` and `/` the script in the accepted answer won't catch it because each part will look like `.` which is simply the current directory.  But a typical UNIX shell treats the `\` as an escape character so passing it `./\.\./` is equivalent to `./../` and so the attacker can exploit the fact that the script combines tests for UNIX and Windows style paths.

If by "security" you really mean you want to provide protection against casual mistakes and typos, then the other answers are probably sufficient.  If you are programming for a hostile environment and want to prevent breaches from deliberate attacks then they barely scratch the surface and you would be well advised to go read up on secure programming at OWASP.  I would start with their [articles on Path Traversal](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal) and then read up on the other attacks they outline as well as how to avoid them and, more importantly, how to test for them.

Comment: I would like to see reference on whether this applies to a path that is stored in a PHP string and is passed to one of the PHP filesystem handling functions. More precisely: I sincerely doubt that if I pass a string to an FS function in PHP that it will do URL-decoding or will interpret backslashes as escape sequences. But I would love to be proven wrong, as this would have severe security implications on many libraries using an approach such as the one I posted above.

Comment: Did you follow the link I provided?  OWASP's example is written in PHP. I also specifically noted in my response that the exact behavior depends on what processes the URL before *and* after PHP gets the string.  It would not surprise me at all if many common libraries are affected since #8 of the OWASP Top 10 Web Application Security Risks is Failure to Restrict URL Access, of which path traversal is one of the prime vectors.  This would not make the OWASP Top 10 if the prevailing practices were sound.

Comment: Yes, i want to make my app really secure, i'm working in local under windows but it could be on linux remotly. I do not understand all what you said, user posts a form i get the values, i check the field, and then for example show the file matching field value. I assume that readfile (or any php functions) interprets strings arg as any others string in php code like a test "$str == '..'". For the `./\.\./` split string, i already made a function that check the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant and replace / or \ to their opposite. I thought it solved the problem.

Comment: If you take nothing else from this post and various responses, the most important advice is: go to the OWASP site and learn, deeply, about web app security. OWASP isn't the only authority on the topic but it's a real good place to start. There is almost no chance of getting web app security right without a deep understanding, reusing existing knowledge and then penetration testing the implementation aggressively.  The intent of my post wasn't to give you more patterns to check but rather to illustrate why it is necessary to gain a deeper understanding of the topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
$folders = $explode('/', $path);

if (in_array('..', $folders)) {
    print('Error: path contains ..');
}
```

Comment: using `..` could still result in a path below the allowed path though, e.g. when `/only/data/below/here` then `/only/data/below/here/foo/..` would still be okay.

Comment: @Gordon: how would you go below without using `..`?

Comment: @PeeHaa, I guess: `/path/to/dir/../../to/dir/samefile`

Comment: @Rob W: But I check if path contains `..`. So that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: `/path/to/dir/../../to/dir/samefile` = `/path/to/dir/samefile`, which should be valid.

Comment: @Rob W: I thought that was what the OP wanted. `i want to test if a path given by the user go down like: ... at the opposite of :`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to restrict the user from going up in the path hierarchy, you can explicitly search for '..':

```
if (1 === preg_match('/\.\./', $path)) {
    /* path contains .. */
}
```

Which is also quicker than explode and in_array.

Benchmarking:

```
<?php

$attempts = 100000;
$path     = 'my/path/with/../invalid';

$t = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $attempts; ++$i) {
  $folders = explode('/', $path);
  if (in_array('..', $folders)) {
    /* .. in path */ ;
  }
}
$end = microtime(true);
printf("in_array: %f\n", $end - $t);

$t = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $attempts; ++$i) {
  if (1 === preg_match('/\.\./', $path)) {
    /* .. in path */ ;
  }
}
$end = microtime(true);
printf("preg_match: %f\n ", $end - $t);
```

> in_array: 0.088750
>
> preg_match: 0.071547